# A property of Legendre transform, Chapter 3, Problem 12, Evans PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, hamilton-jacobi-equation

The problem is: Prove $L_1,L_2:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are convex, smooth and superlinear (that is $L(x)/|x|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$). Show that 
$$
\min\limits_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n}(L_1(v)+L_2(v))=\max\limits_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}(-H_1(p)-H_2(-p)),
$$ 
where $H_1=L_1^*,H_2=L_2^*$.

Here, 
$$
L^*(v)=\sup_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}v\cdot p-L(v).
$$
My try: From the superlinearity of $L_1$ and $L_2$, we know that the min on left side and max on right side are attainable.

By definition of the Legendre transform, for any $v,p\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{equation}
L_1(v)+L_2(v)\geq p\cdot v-H_1(p)+(-p)\cdot v-H_2(-p)=-H_1(p)-H_2(-p)
\label{12-1}
\end{equation}
which implies that
$$
L_1(v)+L_2(v)\geq \max\limits_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}(-H_1(p)-H_2(-p)).
$$
Take min over $v$,
$$
\min\limits_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n}(L_1(v)+L_2(v))\geq \max\limits_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}(-H_1(p)-H_2(-p)).
$$

But how to prove the other direction?